# Save all images in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bunch of graphs with the ggplot2 package. I have set a title on each of my graphs and I would like now to save them all, under the name of the title I've set. Is there a simple way to save them on my computer without having to write the `ggsave("title_of_my_graph.png", plot=my_graph  , height=, width=)` command for each graph in my script ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper around `ggsave()` that saves by title. Example below:

```
ggsave_by_title <- function(plot, ...) {
  fname <- plot$labels$title
  if (is.null(fname)) {
    stop("No title detected")
  }
  fname <- paste0(fname, ".png")
  ggsave(fname, plot = plot, device = "png", ...)
}
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
  ggtitle("Iris")

ggsave_by_title(p, width = 10, height = 5)
```